# How To Embed a video in a body field like facebook does

Tags: files

Do you know please?

Instead of having to click on a button
to embed a video.

Is there a module that hides the embed code in the body field

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cUWFLBZU5I&list=PL15BE2E8313A4E809&feature=share

So when you add the youtube link

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="VIDEO LINK" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It fill in the src link

Many Thanks for your help

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/embed-vimeo-video-into-the-body-field

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly I think that you can use the [Video Filter module](https://drupal.org/project/video_filter).

Video Filter allows you to put something like this in the body:

```
[video:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCLx4fRHmCk]
```

Here you can see a post about this module:

[How to Embed Videos using Video Filter in Drupal 7](http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-embed-videos-using-video-filter-drupal-7)